# Domain name for a community

Tags: partner-communities

If I'm setting up a sandbox, when I select a domain should it be different than what I would like to use in my main org? Or will the domain I use in the sandbox be available to use in my main org when I later create it? I want to make sure if I choose a domain for my sandbox that it won't be later unavailable when I'm ready to implement.

Answer (score 6):

When you select a MyDomain in production, Salesforce will automatically select domains for sandboxes based on the Sandbox name.  That is, if you select `mydomain.my.salesforce.com` for Production, then your QA Sandbox should have the domain `mydomain--qa.my.salesforce.com`.

You can find more information about this [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=faq_domain_name_sandboxes.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=206.8).

To that end, you are probably better off creating the domain in Production (without deploying it to users) and letting it trickle down into the sandboxes.

Comment: Unfortunately, I followed what was advised on the deleted post and my URL looks wierd https://dev1-partners-myorg-dev1.cs31.force.com/

Comment: Can I delete a created community ?

Comment: That's a shame.  I haven't experienced this first hand, but you should be able to open a ticket with SF support to change it.  Either way, you should hold off on deploying the domain to users until you are satisfied with the domain name.

Comment: This only applies if you create the domain in production and then create the sandbox. If you are creating the domain in sandbox for testing, you should still use a unique name. Otherwise you run into this issue: https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000dxMDQAY

Comment: Good point.  I've edited the answer to make that more clear.

Comment: I'm also not sure that I'd recommend that route, since this is for Communities domain not the overall "My Domain" fr the entire org. It seems that it would be more effort than it's worth to create the community in Production and recreate the Sandbox, where there might still be pending work, when you can just create a test community in Sandbox and then use the preferred domain when they are ready to deploy?

Comment: In my experience, it's been a headache having half of the orgs using a custom domain and the other half using the generic.  I guess it's a question of what @Bennie is more comfortable with.  I've never encountered a scenario where domain activation interferes with pending work.

Comment: Not the activation itself, but refreshing the sandbox to bring over the community domain would interfere with pending work (which, to my understanding, is the only way to bring a community from production to sandbox) And it shouldn't be much of a headache because the org domains will be the same, and the new community that he is creating will not be in any other environment

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the sequence of events.  I was enabling MyDomain in a Production org *literally* this week, and once I enabled that I was given the option of deploying a variation on that domain to the sandboxes.  You are right that moving from sandbox to production will be much trickier.  At that point, it seems like the best thing to do would be to open a ticket with CF and have them sort the domain names out for you.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: The question specifically states that he is creating the Domain in Sandbox. The other answer only applies if you create the Domain in Production and then spin up a Sandbox.

If you create a Domain in Sandbox is will *not* be available in Production as seen in [this](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000dxMDQAY) post. so you *should* use a unique domain such as myDomain-test.force.com in Sandbox if you want your Domain to be available when you are ready to implement.

It will be different because "My Domain" must be unique. Don't implement the exact name you want in production in your sandbox org.

Comment: Can you please explain using an example ? If I use `myorg-partners.force.com` then it won't be available in PROD you are saying ? Shall I use `myorg-dev-partners.force.com` while creating in sandbox? So that `myorg-partners.force.com` is available in PROD

Comment: Right. So in sandbox you probably want to make it myorg-partners-test or something so that the exact name you want will still be available in production.

Comment: my URL looks weird now `dev1-partners-myorg-dev1.cs31.force.com`. so dev1 automatically got prefixed. Can you please advise what should be the next course of action ? In Production shall I register the domain now itself? If I migrate the domain from sandbox to Production will it be overridden ?